# MonoGame Jenkins setup for multiple platforms

Tags: jenkins, monogame, xamarin.mac

I'm building a multi-platform game with MonoGame. I'd like to target Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.Mac, Linux and Windows.

My MonoGame solution consists of:

1. XNA content project
2. Game core project (PCL)
3. Platform-specific projects

(3) depend on (2), which depends on (1).

My Jenkins setup is:

- Windows master
- OS X slave
- Linux slave

To my understanding:

- The XNA content project build requires Microsoft's XNA content pipeline and thus must run on Windows
- I can bring the Xamarin.Mac DLLs over to Windows and build from there, but a Mac is required to package and sign a standalone app.

How would you set Jenkins up to build everything?

Comment: Interesting setup. I have no idea how to solve your problem but I would love to know more about how you got this to work? Do you have a blog or something?

Comment: @craftworkgames I'm planning to put up a blog shortly. Check out DDReaper's PCL fork https://github.com/DDReaper/MonoGame and accompanying blog post http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/monogame-building-portable-solutions/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured there was at least two ways of solving this:

1. Break the solution up per-project Nuget packages and build them in the proper environments. This is what I would have done in Maven land. While theoretically possible using MSBuild and Nuget, it's beyond manageable for me at this point.
2. Manually share the project files master->slave and execute relevant build commands on the slaves. This is what I ended up doing. Since my master runs Windows, I mounted the master workspace over smbfs on the slaves.